# Copy constructors in user classes that make use of stl containers

Tags: c++, stl

If an application defines classes in each of which there is only plain data and stl containers in various combinations, e.g. `set< tuple< size_t, vector< shared_ptr< some-interface-class > > > >`.

Moreover, the application doesn't construct stl containers of one type from stl container of another type. The question is: Whether it is correct in such application (in all its classes) to rely on default copy-constructor, `operator=` and `operator==`? and the appropriate operators/constructors of stl containers?

Are there pitfalls in defining user's `X::X(const X&)` in classes that use only plain data an stl containers?

Comment: It is correct to rely on default copy constructors and there are a lot of pitfalls in defining a new one. Don't do it!

Comment: There is no default `operator==`, that you *have* to define. Everything else can be the default generated ones. The standard library types are designed to act correctly on (single threaded) copy/move/assignment.

Comment: Are you sure that these classes really need copy constructors?